# How to validate CSS when 0 values do not have units

Tags: css, validation

Trying to validate our CSS files , when running tests the Jigsaw tool says some of our 0 values do not have units , but we cannot find what line of CSS they're referring to.

CSS URL : https://ik.imagekit.io/mqpttb8ig/cv-16-2-2021_eL_A9soPu.css

Can someone please let me know which 0 value is preventing validation here?

Regards,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few 0 values in your file—across margin, padding, and outline properties—but they are fine, 0 values do not need units to be appended to them.

On another note, there are way too many `important` flags and magic numbers—I’d worry about them more.

Comment: Yea we added !important to override default CSS which doesn't exist anymore so i could probably remove most !important - I was trying to get the Validation for .CSS file which won't show until I remove the units issue (jigsaw).